# Flutter: deleting an element from a list doesn't delete corresponding UI element generated with loop

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a DataTable where i add the DataRows with a for loop to the UI. The loop iterates over a list. Over the UI, it is possible to add and remove items from the list.

Like in the picture, every DataRow has TextFormFields in order to get some inputs.
Here is my problem: When i put some values in the TextFields of the rows and then delete one of those rows, always the last row gets deleted, despite me changing the values in the List and updating the state accordingly.

[DataTableRows with TextFormFields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxPwd.png)

So if i for example try to delete the first row in the picture where the weight is set to 10, the value 10 is still there in the first row after the last row disappeared. Since i update the state when i delete the row, and the inputs all have their initialValues set to correspond with the values in the List, shouldn't the row with the 10 disappear? Or is there something wrong with my thought process?
The print statement show that the right ListItem gets deleted, so i am not quite sure what is happening here.

I am really new to Flutter and Dart, so any help is appreciated!

Here the Code of the Table:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:pr_note_app/definitions/ExerciseSet.dart';

class ExerciseTable extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;

  ExerciseTable({Key key, @required this.name}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExerciseTableState createState() => _ExerciseTableState();
}

class _ExerciseTableState extends State<ExerciseTable> {
  var _sets = [new ExerciseSet("-", "", "")];

  void popUpMenuButtonItemSelected(value) {
    switch (value) {
      case "Add Set":
        setState(() {
          _sets.add(new ExerciseSet("-", "", ""));
        });
        break;
      default:
    }
  }

  void removeSetAt(index) {
    print(_sets);
    setState(() {
      _sets.removeAt(index);
    });
    print(_sets);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          title: TextFormField(
            initialValue: widget.name,
            cursorColor: Colors.black,
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: "My New Exercise"),
          ),
          actions: [
            PopupMenuButton(
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry>[
                const PopupMenuItem(value: "Add Set", child: Text("Add Set")),
                const PopupMenuItem(
                    value: "Remove Exercise", child: Text("Remove Exercise"))
              ],
              onSelected: (value) => popUpMenuButtonItemSelected(value),
            ),
          ],
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        // SET NUMBER | LAST | WEIGHT | REPS
        DataTable(
          showCheckboxColumn: false,
          columnSpacing: 30,
          columns: const <DataColumn>[
            DataColumn(
              label: Text(
                'Set',
                style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
              ),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text(
                'Last',
                style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
              ),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text(
                'Weight',
                style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
              ),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text(
                'Reps',
                style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
              ),
            ),
            DataColumn(label: Text(""))
          ],
          rows: [
            for (var i = 0; i < _sets.length; i++)
              DataRow(onSelectChanged: (bool) => print("select $bool"), cells: [
                // SET NUMBER
                DataCell(Text("${i + 1}")),
                // LAST
                DataCell(Text("${_sets[i].last}")),
                // WEIGHT
                DataCell(Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.13,
                    child: TextFormField(
                        initialValue: "${_sets[i].weight}",
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _sets[i].weight = value;
                          });
                        },
                        cursorColor: Colors.black,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          isDense: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                          filled: true,
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                          enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                          errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                          disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                        )))),
                // REPS
                DataCell(Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.13,
                    child: TextFormField(
                        initialValue: "${_sets[i].reps}",
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _sets[i].reps = value;
                          });
                        },
                        cursorColor: Colors.black,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          isDense: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                          filled: true,
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                          enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                          errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                          disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                        )))),
                DataCell(Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.13,
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                    onPressed: () => removeSetAt(i),
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ))
              ])
          ],
        )
      ],
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is probably that the framework can't figure out which state to assign to the items.
You need to add key to `DataRow`:

```
DataKey(
key: ObjectKey(_sets[i]),
...
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much!

What i ended up using:

DataRow(
  key: UniqueKey(),
  ...
)

Comment: Would you say using hashCode is preferable to UniqueKey()?

Comment: If you use `UniqueKey`, every time you rebuild with setState, it will set different key for the items. I think the Key(val) or ObjectKey(obj) is the best in your case.